# Очистка tmp каталога Debian

Tags: linux, debian

Всем привет!
Столкнулся с проблемой - постоянно заполнен каталог tmp на сервере.

Команда

`df -i /tmp`

выдает

```
Filesystem      Inodes   IUsed IFree IUse% Mounted on
/dev/sda1      1564672 1564672     0  100% /
```

Подскажите, как правильно очистить tmp каталог или может увеличить его размер?

Comment: Для начала лучше выяснить, кто туда пишет и что.

Comment: лучше найти того, кто закгаживает его и научить хорошим манерам удаления временных файлов... и удостоверься, точно ли /tmp виноват: `du --inodes -s /tmp`... в корне много-чего ещё есть

Comment: команда `du --inodes -s /tmp` выдала `2 /tmp`

Comment: А что дает `du -h /tmp` ?

Comment: `4.0K /tmp/.X11-unix
4.0K /tmp/.Test-unix
4.0K /tmp/systemd-private-ae1063515faa4657bf3d72ead71b361d-systemd-timesyncd.service-HGjPqY/tmp
8.0K /tmp/systemd-private-ae1063515faa4657bf3d72ead71b361d-systemd-timesyncd.service-HGjPqY
4.0K /tmp/.webmin
4.0K /tmp/.ICE-unix
4.0K /tmp/.font-unix
4.0K /tmp/.XIM-unix
36K /tmp`

Comment: Всего 36 kB. Место занимает кто-то другой. Посмотрите `var`, к примеру.

Comment: нашел проблему в каталоге `/var/www/html/domain.com/Maildir/new/`, почему так - буду выяснять

Comment: так весь раздел забит... удалите почтовик с сервера или выключите. похоже через вас спам кто-то отправлял